# How can I navigate to a class interface?

Tags: ide, filetype-php

I've been using PHP Storm IDE for some time and I want to try out Vim. PHP Storm automatically allowed me to jump to classess/interfaces defined somewhere in my code (by `use` and `implements` statements, and alike) by double clicking on them. Can I do the same in Vim?

For example, I am in `/app/models/User.php` that implements `UserInterface` defined in `app/interfaces/UserInterface.php`. I want to double click on that name and it would automatically take me to that file.

Comment: There are a few plugins which implement this, such as tagbar and taglist.

Comment: In 2019 I would recommend installing the `phpactor` plugin

Answer (score 5):

You can use the external program [exuberant cTags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to help you doing that: It will create a tags file indexing the keywords of your codebase and allow you to navigate through them.

(The first steps comes from [another answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3666/1841))

- **Install exuberant cTags:** `$ sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags` (or the equivalent command for your distribution).
- **Generate the tags file:** `$ ctags *.php` a file named `tags` should be generated on your folder.
- **Let Vim knows where is your tags file:** `:tags=./tags,tags` with these settings Vim looks for a tags file in the directory of the current file
  and in the working directory. Note that you can use `:set tags?` to check your current configuration.
- **Jump from keyword to declaration** and inversely with `<C-]>` and `g<C-]>`
- **Open a preview window showing the declaration** with `<C-w>}`

I've never used it with php but it should work just like with other languages

Comment: I started using preview windows for this kind of thing, by using `ctrl-w }`.

Comment: @Vitor I didn't know this feature but that seems to be pretty useful!